# How can i add Grid View after Divider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

here is my code i have run the code but no output show

```
 Divider(thickness: 5),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 5),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Best Destination",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  Text("SEE ALL")
                ],
              ),
            ),
            GridView(
              gridDelegate:
                  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping `GridView` with `Expanded` when top level widget is `Column`

```dart
class GriVIssue extends StatelessWidget {
  const GriVIssue({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Divider(thickness: 5),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 5),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Best Destination",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal, fontSize: 20),
                ),
                Text("SEE ALL")
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: GridView(
              gridDelegate:
                  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Check more on this [Unbounded height / width | Decoding Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI&vl=en)